# How to remove focus from a button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus

I have a panel on which there is a button.But there is a problem. I need to use KeyEventHandler to catch the Enter press, the button is pressing, and the event is not processed. I tried artificially giving focus to Form, but it didn't help.If I don't add buttons, everything works fine. Can you tell me how to solve this?

I created a new project and tried: with the button, the Event is not called, and the button is pressed, without the button, the event is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to enable KeyPreview property of that form, to catch a KeyEventHandler. Also check that your AcceptButton property has correct value

Comment: I'm set to AcceptButton null and enable keypreview. But when i press enter KeyEventhandler does not handle exactly pressing enter because .net thinks that I want to select a button with the arrows on the keyboard and press it with enter.Is it possible to disable it somehow?